# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{||a + xb|| - ||a||}{x}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Non-zero vectors a, b, s.t. $||b||=1$, angle of $a$ and $b$ is $\pi/4$.

Calculate the limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{||a + xb|| - ||a||}{x}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\Vert a+xb \Vert - \Vert a \Vert}x & = \dfrac{\Vert a+xb \Vert^2 - \Vert a \Vert^2}{x \left(\Vert a+xb \Vert + \Vert a \Vert\right)}\\
& = \dfrac{\Vert a \Vert^2 +2x \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + x^2 \Vert b \Vert^2 - \Vert a \Vert^2}{x \left(\Vert a+xb \Vert + \Vert a \Vert\right)}\\
& = \dfrac{2x \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + x^2 \Vert b \Vert^2}{x \left(\Vert a+xb \Vert + \Vert a \Vert\right)}\\
& = \dfrac{2 \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + x \Vert b \Vert^2}{\left(\Vert a+xb \Vert + \Vert a \Vert\right)}\\
\end{align}
Now let $x \to 0$ and conclude the limit.

Comment: Note that the "trick" is the same one as the trick you used in finding the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ from first principles. Recall that you looked at $\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}$, and multiplied top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}$.